# Webpack-dev-server Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I am new to webpack. I am attempting to run webpack-dev-server with follows in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

However once I run `npm start`, it always return below message:

```
Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
```

I had came across solutions on Github or Stackoverflow, and I followed them to reinstall my webpack dev server to a lower version nor reinstall the webpack but still not working.

Below are my devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.15.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.5.1",
    "webpack-serve": "^3.2.0"
  }
```

Thank you very much.

**Update**

I had followed the below guide to install webpack-dev-server:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-server

Which I run:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server
```

on vscode.

Then I added below to the webpack file:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
  },
```

Then in package.json add

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server",
        "build": "webpack --mode production",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
```

Then `npm start`, which would throw the error below:

```
maikerunoMacBook-Pro:hello-world michaelcheng$ npm start

> hello-world@0.1.0 start /Users/michaelcheng/Documents/proj/hello-world
> webpack serve --open

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /Users/michaelcheng/Documents/proj/hello-world
ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
⚠ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 1215ba9f4ef933607cb0
Version: webpack 4.44.2
Time: 2756ms
Built at: 01/19/2021 10:25:21 PM
    Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
1.main.js  3.41 KiB       1  [emitted]         
  main.js   517 KiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
Entrypoint main [big] = main.js
  [0] ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes {0} [built]
  [9] ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 1.33 KiB {0} [built]
 [46] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/log.js 964 bytes {0} [built]
 [60] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
 [61] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 4.29 KiB {0} [built]
 [62] (webpack)-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
 [64] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.53 KiB {0} [built]
 [67] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.51 KiB {0} [built]
 [74] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/sendMessage.js 402 bytes {0} [built]
 [75] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js 1.59 KiB {0} [built]
 [78] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js 2.91 KiB {0} [built]
 [86] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {0} [built]
 [92] ./src/index.css 658 bytes {0} [built]
[103] ./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 530 KiB {0} [built]
[104] ./src/index.js + 79 modules 375 KiB {0} [built]
      | ./src/index.js 566 bytes [built]
      | ./src/App.js 397 bytes [built]
      | ./src/reportWebVitals.js 511 bytes [built]
      | ./src/HelloWorld.js 299 bytes [built]
      | ./src/signin.js 3.48 KiB [built]
      | ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Avatar/Avatar.js 6.7 KiB [built]
      | ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Button/Button.js 14.1 KiB [built]
      | ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/CssBaseline/CssBaseline.js 2.52 KiB [built]
      | ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/styles/useTheme.js 398 bytes [built]
      | ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/TextField/TextField.js 11.4 KiB [built]
      | ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Typography/Typography.js 7.99 KiB [built]
      | ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/FormControlLabel/FormControlLabel.js 5.21 KiB [built]
      | ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Checkbox/Checkbox.js 6.88 KiB [built]
      | ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Link/Link.js 5.04 KiB [built]
      | ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Grid/Grid.js 13.2 KiB [built]
      |     + 65 hidden modules
    + 160 hidden modules

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  main.js (517 KiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (517 KiB)
      main.js

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
^C
maikerunoMacBook-Pro:hello-world michaelcheng$ npm start

> hello-world@0.1.0 start /Users/michaelcheng/Documents/proj/hello-world
> webpack-dev-server

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- /Users/michaelcheng/Documents/proj/hello-world/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/michaelcheng/Documents/proj/hello-world/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/michaelcheng/Documents/proj/hello-world/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-world@0.1.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-world@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/michaelcheng/.npm/_logs/2021-01-19T13_25_44_633Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of [webpack/webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server#with-npm-scripts) you should run `webpack serve` instead of `webpack-dev-server`.

Try replacing in your package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve",
    // ...
```

Than run `npm start` again.